# Angular 5. Checking parents *ngIf in children component

Tags: angular, boolean, components, angular5, angular-ng-if

I have two pages (**`diary.component`** and **`redactor.component`**) both draws the same component **`food.component`**, only with small difference: if it's **`diary.component`** - food should have an "add button". If it's **`redactor.component`** - food should have a delete button. I tried to solve this problem with boolean in parent components and check this state in **`food.component.html`** using *ngIf, but it doesn't work. Whats the problem, and how can I solve this? 
Here's my code for better understanding:

**diary.component.ts**

```
isDiary: boolean;
ngOnInit() {
    this.isDiary = true;
}
```

**food.component.html**

```
<div class="food">

  <button *ngIf="isDiary; else isRedactor" (click)="sendFood(food.name, food.nutritional_value)" class="add-btn" type="button">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </button>

  <ng-template #isRedactor>
    <button><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
  </ng-template>
  ...
</div>
```

Thank you !

Comment: So the food.component.html is the template that both diary.component and redactor.component are displaying? You could try *ngIf="isDiary === true; else isRedactor" the other option is instead of setting isDiary to true in the ngOnInit(), assign it when you declare it.

Comment: Exactly ! But in doesn't work. I already check using *ngIf. Maybe, it is problem with context...Cause i check state from other component..I dont know

Answer (score 5):

you have to create

```
@Input() isDiary: boolean;
```

inside of food.component.ts and pass the value from parent like so

```
<your-food-component [isDiary]="isDiary"></your-food-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm assuming it's now always showing the add button?

This would be understandable, as you set your boolean to true in ngOnInit which will always happen when the component initializes!

Basically what you want is probably the definition of an @Input (https://angular.io/guide/component interaction) so you can conditionally pass it from the parent!

Using this way you can provide true in the parent where the add button should be shown and false in the parent where your else path should be taken!